# Find the derivative of $f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin (t^2)}{1+\cos^2t}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I was requested to find the derivative of

$$f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin (t^2)}{1+\cos^2t}dt$$

if that derivative exists. It is the first problem of the sort I face and just want to make sure my approach is correct.

*My solution.*

$i$. The fundamental theorem of calculus establishes that, if $f$ is continuous at $[a, b]$, then  $g(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is continuous at $[a, b]$ and differentiable at $(a, b)$, and satisfies $g'(x)=f(x)$

$ii.$ Let $g(x) := \frac{\sin (x^2)}{1+\cos^2x}$. It is easy to see $g$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, for there is no real $x$ satisfying $1+\cos^2 x = 0$.

$iii.$ In consequence, due to the FTC, $$f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin (t^2)}{1+\cos^2t}dt$$

is continuous and differentiable in $(-\infty, \infty )$ and satisfies $f'(x)= \frac{\sin (x^2)}{1+\cos^2x}$.

I know this is a basic problem, thank you in advanced for correcting any errors or giving the okay.

Comment: Everything is correct. What exactly are your doubts about it?

Comment: I wanted someone to validate my approach, since I am studying solo. I have no professors, no solutions to my excercises, etc., which makes me sometimes weary of whether my answers are actually right. Thank you so much!

Comment: Minor point in i. : $g(x) = \int_a^b f(t) \ dt$ is meaningless, perhaps you mean $\int_a^{\color{red}{x}} f(t) \ dt$?

Comment: @Gregory thanks! Just a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: For future reference you can use Wolfram alpha to check most of your answers if you are self studying.

Answer (score 1):

Via the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_c^x f(t)dt = f(x)$$For all constants c. Therefore $f′(x)=\frac{sin(x^2)}{1+cos^2(x)}$ is correct